# Deleting MANY url_rewrite rows with a lock?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

**Magento 2.2**

I have to run a huge SQL script which deletes around 2 million entries from `url_rewrite` by entity_id. This script runs a couple of days, but is interrupted by other processes and so I always get the deadlock SQL error and the script is aborted and I have to restart it manually.

Now I was thinking to write lock `url_rewrite` while the script runs. How would I do that and is it a good idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Split the delete querie to batch

like

```
$batchSize = 1000;
$maxUrlRewriteId = $db->fetchOne('select max(id) from url_rewrite');
for ($i =0; $i<= $maxUrlRewriteId; $i++ ) {
    $db->query('delete from url_rewrite where id between $i*$batchSize and $batchSize * ($i+1) and (your filters here)'
}
```